# How {}.hasOwnProperty() works?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have an object `var a = {"1": 1, "2": 2}` and an array `var b = [1, 2]`

What is the difference between the two below?

```
a.hasOwnProperty('1'); // Returns true
b.indexOf(1); // Returns 0, which is the index
```

While calling both methods, will a `for` loop play a role? Are both equal complexity wise?

Thank you for your explanation...

Comment: Because `{}` is an object and not an array, arrays have indexes and objects have properties.

Comment: @Imaginaroom did you check the question correctly? I have used `{}` for the sample only

Comment: `var a = {"1": 1, "2": 2}` is an Object. `var b = [1, 2]` is an Array. An Array is a type of Object, and Object is _not_ a type of Array.

Comment: `a.hasOwnProperty()` is doing a key lookup which should be O(1)

Comment: FYI: `hasOwnProperty` expects property **_name_**, not _value_

Comment: @NickParsons that's another great answer, that's what I want `Order` thank you so much

Comment: @hindmost yeah, that's correct, that's why I passed `key` to `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: @NickParsons - It'll depend on whether the object is in optimized mode (which it will be above, almost certainly) or dictionary mode, but in any case, it's going to be sublinear, so rather faster than `indexOf`. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ah, interesting. Thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the difference between below two

The first one tells you whether the object has a property with the *name* `"1"`. The second tells you whether the array has an *entry* with the *value* 1, and if so, where it is in the array. Those are very different things. Note that the `hasOwnProperty` isn't looking at the *value* of the property at all, just whether it exists. You'd get the same result (`true`) from `({"1": "foo", "2": "bar"}).hasOwnProperty("1")`.

> Here my questions are, while calling both methods, will `for` loop plays a role?

Not in `hasOwnProperty`, on any modern JavaScript engine. Yes in `indexOf`.

> and complexity wise both are equal?

No, not at all. `indexOf` will be linear (`O(n)`). `hasOwnProperty` will be less than that, often dramatically less than that. Even in the worst case (an unoptimized object), it will be more along the lines of a hashed dictionary lookup.

Comment: Superb, this is the answer I am expecting from the SO guys. Thank you so much. Then how `hasOwnProperty` finds the element then? :-)

Comment: @JavascriptLover-SKT - How is up to the JavaScript engine implementation, and it can vary even within an engine. Engines aggressively optimize objects for property retrieval since that's overwhelmingly what we use them for. For example, V8 creates and compiles a class for an object, subclassing when you add a property to the object. But some operations, such as `delete`, can make it fall back to "dictionary" mode where it's basically a hash map.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder How do you know all this, can you give me some source so that I can study all this?

Comment: @SurajJain - I've learned from lots of different places over 25 years or so. :-) [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/javascript) is quite good. I read [the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/) when I want to know how something is supposed to work (the language and conventions used in it are a bit daunting though). I read questions and answers here. If you want to know how the new stuff in ES2015 onward works, I've written a book. :-D Links in my profile.

Comment: Your book is about new things in ES6, but currently I want to understand the deep fundamentals, where can I find that?

Comment: @SurajJain - Probably other books. :-) Axel Rauschmayer knows his stuff and has the book [Deep JavaScript](https://exploringjs.com/deep-js/) (I think it's still in progress but the first parts are already available). I haven't read it (or his other books), but again, he knows his stuff pretty well.

Comment: Thanks, will refer to those, and with time also get to yours :)